# How are proofs in group theory involving group actions valid when we choose a particular group action? Doesn't that involve a loss of generality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For example, I am looking at a proof of Cayley's theorem that uses the action of a group on itself by left translation. I understand the proof, but have a hard time seeing why we're working with a specific group action, because doing that makes it seem like we're using some trickery and there are a ton of group actions to choose from so why are we choosing left translation and not, say, conjugation?

Comment: Group actions can be faithful or not.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I don't understand the connection b/w faithfulness and my question. Can you give more details? Further, this theorem was proven in class before the definitions for the different types of group actions were given.

Comment: @J.Doe A group action that isn't faithful will not produce an embedding (a 1-1 map). So... it seems pretty relevant.

Comment: "because doing that makes it seem like we're using some trickery". I wouldn't call this trickery. We can apply any specific group action if it gives what we want. Like showing that $239$ is not the sum of two squares we "apply" looking at it modulo $4$. What a "trickery" you would say, right? There are "tons of moduli to chose from so why are we choosing $4$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every action will work, and in particular conjugation will not work if $Z(G)$ is non-trivial. We need to pick an action with a specific property, and left translation just so happens to have this property. Right translation will also work, for example.

For an action to work in the proof of Cayley's theorem you need that every element moves *something* in the action, which is called a *[faithful action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Faithful)*. That is, for all $g\in G$ we need an $x\in G$ such that $g\cdot x\neq x$ (here, I am acting by $g$). Otherwise, if $g$ fixes everything then it is contained in the kernel of the action and our map $G\rightarrow S_{|G|}$ is not an injection. Left translation ensures that every non-trivial element moves something. However, conjugation can have fixed points (every element of $Z(G)$).

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't such proofs be valid? After all the Cayley's theorem **is not** about any group action. The particular group action is only used as a tool to prove it.

Such choices are all over maths. For example how often do you use natural numbers as a particularly important set? Or the sphere $S^1$, so important in algebraic geometry? And so on, and so on...

Comment: Your reasoning that this isn't a theorem about group actions seems solid. The examples that you're talking about, however, and the theorems that I've seen being proven in different subjects don't go about proving general statements in the same manner that I'm talking about. If you can point to an instance that's would help me see the similarities, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: @J.Doe Fair enough. Consider this statement: "every subgroup of a free group is free". At first it looks like completely unrelated to spheres and topology. Purely algebraic statement. Yet the only proof I know is based on fundamental groups of a bouquet of circles. Which are carefully chosen, concrete objects. This is also known as [Nielsen-Schreier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem).